# How to check the browser's Storage object whether it is localStorage or sessionStorage to manage the static/dynamic secret keys in client?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, session-storage

I design a decoratable storage services in which an example is like `getExpirableStorage(getSecureStorage(getLocalStorage() | getSessionStorage()))` in typescript/javascript.

To implement `getSecureStorage` I was using a **hardcoded static cipher key** and encrypting every value of key/value pair which is to be added to local or session storage.

Since we already keep the cipher key in client, I have decided to **dynamically generated key after every expire** to prevent the case of the user somehow gets the key from source and share that keys with others. In this case I need to store the every new cipherKey for every distinct key/value.

```js
createSecureStorage(storage: Storage): Storage { 
    var cipherKeyMap = this.keyMapping;
    let privateState = function() {
        let cipherKey;
        this.encrypt = function(key: string, data: string): string {
          let entry = cipherKeyMap.find(entry => entry.key === key);
          if (entry) {
            cipherKey = entry.cipherKey;
          } else {
            cipherKey = Array.from({length: 16}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 90));
            cipherKeyMap.push({"key": key, "cipherKey": cipherKey});
          //...
        };

        this.decrypt = function(key: string, data: string): string {
          //...
        };
    }
    let state = new privateState();

    return {
      setItem(key: string, value: string) {
        //...
      },
      getItem(key: string) {
        //...
      },

      //is triggered from expirableSecureStorage
      removeItem(key: string) {
        storage.removeItem(key);
        cipherKeyMap.splice(cipherKeyMap.findIndex(r => r.key === key), 1);
      }
    } 
  }
```

Above function works for both `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` which have the type of `Storage` and is also exported as

```js
//lib.dom.d.ts
declare var sessionStorage: Storage;
declare var localStorage: Storage;
```

This services will be used for several cases from multiple clients for the values that will be kept in these storages.

---

For the `createSecureStorage` function I realized that if the storage passed is `localStorage`, when the user close the tab/window the **application state will wipe out and I will lose the cipher keys but related data will stay in local storage as encrypted with these keys**.

I think I have to do one of this ones:

1. Manage the persistence or clearance of cipher keys randomly generated in the case of localStorage.
2. Or put only values that will be excrypted with hardcoded static cipher key to localStorage and put the values that will be encrypted by dynamically generated cipher keys to sessionStorage

I choose #2 because I don't want to persist the cipher keys in client since we current status also is not ideally secure.

Thus, to do that I think I need the distinguish localStorage from sessionStorage.

How can I distinguish sessionStorage from localStorage?

Comment: you might try `instanceof` operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: @canbax, thank you, but each of localStorage and secureStorage is type of `Storage`, how can I use it?

Comment: you might try implementing 2 different functions for each of them

Comment: I have thought that, but I think It would duplicate the code. Which part do you think we can implement without duplicating much?

Comment: you can minimize the duplication. Just write 2 functions with different names and call a common function that does the job.

Comment: Be aware that even if the `localStorage` object exists, you might not be able to store data on it due to private browsing, citrix, lacking local access to *AppData* and probably some more.

Comment: @canbax, I have added other parts for the points to take care when thinking about duplication. Note that these are decorators and I have other functions such as `createExpirableSecureStorage` or `createLocalStorage` etc. While said this, which part actually do you think I can put a common method and how to dispatch it?

Comment: Simply I don't know. I don't know much about your structure

Answer (score 1):

To find out whether your passed object is `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` you can just compare them, since objects are compared by reference.

```
function getStorage(storage){console.log(storage === localStorage)};
getStorage(localStorage);
getStorage(sessionStorage);
```